# PyQt5 QWebEngine disable Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to make my program remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin on any website it goes to, how can I do this? Here is the code I have right now:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
    self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("thewebsite"))
    self.webView.loadFinished.connect(self.reform)
    self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.webView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
  def reform(self, ok):
    payload = open('payload.js', 'r').read()
    if ok:
        self.webView.page().runJavaScript('alert("Ready");')
        self.webView.page().runJavaScript(payload)
  def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  MainWindow.setFixedSize(500, 500)
  MainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I make it so it disables Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: Why do you want to disable it? Maybe there is another method for your main objective.

Comment: I need to disable it so that I can make post requests to other websites, currently I cant do that because I cant interact with any other websites due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin. I know this is possible to accomplish because I saw somebody do it in Qt, I just don't know how to do it in PyQt5

Comment: Do you have the solution link for Qt ?, if you provide me with the link, I could translate it to PyQt.

Comment: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qtwebengine/2015-November/000237.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try enabling the [`LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls` WebAttribute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settings = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.defaultSettings()
    settings.setAttribute(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
    ...
```